# visual studio 2013 intellisense for html tags

Tags: visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I am trying to add some custon tags for my directives into the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Packages\schemas\html\html5.xsd, hoping to have autocomplete on the element name, once I do that.

But all my attemps have failed.

I did:

```
<xsd:element name="my-custom-tag">
    <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
        <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:group ref="flowContent" />
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

and I added this element to

```
<xsd:group name="flowContent">
    <xsd:choice>

        <xsd:element ref="my-custom-tag" />

    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:group>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of, that file is actualy named "html_5.xsd" (with an underscore), was it just a typo?

Second, did you restart VS after that?

And also try deleting the "html_5.bin" file before starting VS, I think that is a precompiled cache.